# encoding URL parameter in Ruby, and correctly decoding it with php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-encoding, urldecode

I want to encode an URL parameter with Ruby.
The URL parameter not encoded is like this:

```
index.php?hash=tlNmgzWNFelvIH1o9ZAWFifpB3RwZOh6DCt5OdIfJCWLo9iZSRONWk1D1rEnSxUp|hi8JcsAHkznPkDFfaS1+xw==
```

Then I want to decode it from PHP!

I tried ruby:

```
ERB::Util::url_encode(param)
```

And then in Php urldecode($param); does not seem to work!

Answer (score 16):

Use `CGI::escape` on rubyside.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape

```
url_encoded_string = CGI::escape("'Stop!' said Fred")
   # => "%27Stop%21%27+said+Fred"
```

Comment: if i want to encode only "+" symbol not the whole string any suggestion?